# How to set profiles as default in thorntail 2.4

Tags: jakarta-ee, thorntail

**Problem:**
I created an application in JavaEE with Thorntail 2.4.0-Final.
I have 2 yaml Files, 'project-default.yml' and 'project-local.yml'.
My Postgres information are inside the default.yml, my H2 information inside the local.yml.

If I start my application with the command line 'java -jar myapplication.jar' it will use the default.yml. If I add -Slocal to the command line it uses the local.yml, but I want it to use as default the local.yml.

I know I can rename the 2 yaml files, so that the default will be the H2, but this doesn't solve my problem, because I want to deploy my application into a Cloud and in the Cloud it should use the Postgres and not the H2 and there is no option to say something like 'cf push myapplication -S....'.

**Question:**
How can I tell my application that he use the 'project-local.yml' file when I start my application local, without adding '-Slocal'?

Or

How can I push my application with adding a command to say which yaml file it should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thorntail can't know in which environment it's running. The very purpose of configuration profiles is that *you* are in control of what configuration is applied. If you have an idea how a "local" environment could be reliably (!) detected, I think that would be a great feature request.

That said, it seems weird that Cloud Foundry wouldn't let you configure the command that's used to start the app. Per http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html, you can use the `-c` argument to configure the command.

This seems pretty low-level, though, so here's another option. In addition to the `-s` and `-S` arguments, you can use the `thorntail.project.stage.file` and `thorntail.project.stage` system properties. Here, you can set `thorntail.project.stage`, which is roughly equivalent to `-S`. Per https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-java_opts.md, you can set arbitrary system properties by creating the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

So if you switched `project-defaults.yml` to the local settings (using H2), and created e.g. `project-cloud.yml` with the production settings (using PostgreSQL), it would be enough to create an environment variable `JAVA_OPTS="-Dthorntail.project.stage=cloud"` in Cloud Foundry.

Comment: Please, read: https://github.com/fraballi/thorntail-microservices-multiple-profiles

Comment: @FelixAballi -- you're saying that the environment variable `THORNTAIL_PROJECT_STAGE` also works, in addition to a system property `-Dthorntail.project.stage`? I don't think that was ever an intention, but makes sense and is actually a good point. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed @ladicek, also tested both approaches in previous project link. That's why I wanted to provide a broader scope, also if you were working with containerized microservices but also handling multiple profiles: dev, test, prod. Also, JVM detects variables defined in those scopes, even if they weren't directly set through: -D'property.name' convention. ;-)